# What android browser is capable of transmitting multitouch events?

Tags: android, browser, multi-touch

I've got a new Samsung Note that has a lot of touch points accessible via the hardware...but I can't seem to get 2 simultaneous touch events registered in the browser, tried quite some demo apps I've found online. (there's a bunch of them listed [in this presentation](http://smustalks.appspot.com/touch-11/#21))

I also tried various browsers: Firefox (beta), the default browser, and Dolphin HD... but neither seems to be able to get it right.

Anybody else got this working perhaps, or knows why it doesn't?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Jochen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera Mobile 11 supports multitouch.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Samsung has customized WebKit on the Note and broke multi-touch handling. Good luck getting definitive answers on that either way.
But, does [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html) help?

Comment: Thx, but I tried Firefox and Dolphin HD too without success so guess not. I already explored the HTML5 rocks site and lots of others testing all examples I found without succes until now.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html
Android 2.3.3 (which should be very close to the one Galaxy Note uses, 2.3.6) does not support multitouch in the browser.

You may want to try Firefox for Android (I haven't tried that).

Comment: The native browser perhaps has iessues, but I tried Firefox and Dolphin too... so that still doesn't really solve the question, but thx for the input of course! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a go at this [MultiTouch Polyfill](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill). It enables you to create a multitouch enabled WebView - which most android 2.x devices (such as the Samsung Note) don't have by default despite the device registering more.

Haven't tested it with the mentioned demo apps from the presentation, but i can say it works for the [scripty2 Touchspector](http://scripty2.com/demos/touch/touchspector/) as well as pinch zooming OpenLayers and Google Maps.

If this will be helpful, i'd be happy to bundle it up as browser application and put it on the market so you have something to test touch applications with on a 2.x device.

Comment: thanks! love the scripty2 Touchinspector! please keep me updated if you don't mind :) will try to keep this thread updated too if I might find something interesting.

Comment: Thx! guess the most important update is that WMP has been suggested for http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/RoadmapProjects - However i wouldn't wait for it if you need it today.

If you don't want to miss any new version or bugfix release (and maybe also want to help with feedback and your device specs), i strongly suggest you click the "watch" button on our github page.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome beta works too! Perhaps even better than Opera Mobile...but slower.